# Rendering just Grease Pencil masked out by other Mesh Objects

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, grease-pencil

I am using Cycles in the latest Blender stable release.

I need to understand if there is a way to just render the Grease Pencil objects without the 3d mesh objects, but the Grease pencil objects would need to be masked out by 3d mesh objects.

The underlying issue.
I am trying to use Render Farms to render some of the bigger Blend files that are composed of 3d objects + Grease Pencil objects. Most of the Render Farms seems are not able to render Grease Pencil objects and the ones that can are out of my price range.

So I am wondering if it is possible for me to render the Grease Pencil objects on my own local machine (as it does not seem to be CPU intensive) then composite them together with the Render Farm's output.

Some things to note, the grease pencil output would need to be a transparent background so I can overlay it over the 3d output when compositing.

I am fairly new to blender and have been googling Combined and Z Passes for a way to achieve this. Maybe I am not using the right combination of keywords, hoping someone can point me the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are using Cycles.

1. Don't forget to enable transparency (RGBA in output also):

[image]

2. Disable overlays and switch to viewport shading mode:

[image]

3. Then render using View → Viewport Render Animation

[image]

Unfortunately, standard render does not work here due to this [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T75240)